# How do I dynamically create components from templates and data requested via an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, templates, mustache

The goal of the project is to display panels that are customisable at the backend and so we receive the template and the data of the panels from a backend API, the components at the client-side are not predefined and I have to display content by merging template json and a data json which are fetched from an API and I am currently using `MustacheJS` and `react-mustache-template-component` to acheive this. I can easily create lists and simple components.

But the problem comes while creating components with interactivity, not simple lists, but swipeable graphs , charts and carousels; And Mustache templates do not help me achieve this, furthermore, since I am using react-mustache-template package I can only use pure HTML elements in my templates , custom React components or library components do not work, how do I solve this problem?

Or is there a different way to approach this problem, the design of the templates are not yet fixed and I went with Mustache because it satisfied my initial use-case, but now the panels are getting more interactive. Is there a different way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- If all graphs, charts and carousels look the same: I would simply write down the code.
- If not, i would define specify some json structure that defines what to do with what. Example of showing an alert when clicking a button:

```
[
    {
        "identifier": "#button",
        "action": {
            "name": "click",
            "handler": {
                "type": "alert",
                "content": "clicked me!"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

On last cases, there is *eval* function, but the use of it is strongly discouraged.

Comment: And how would you render this in the frontend?

Comment: Just to clarify, what I purposed would be to only write a few predefined functions, fetch some .json file in order to know where to bind and what function to trigger. Maybe you make could do something fancier like accepting a array of handlers, or accept action.name = "swipe" and do whatever you want.